# React Hooks: How to get data from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the array of objects which contain components and title now I would like to display these components based on id passed in URL parameters I can do that if its just array using find function, unfortunately, I can't figure how to do the same with an array of objects,

Here is part of my code

```
  //array of objects
 const templates =[
  {
    title: "TemplateOne",
    component: TemplateOne,
  },
  {
    title: "TemplateTwo",
    component: TemplateTwo,
  }]

 //find the component and match the id passed in URL parameters
let SelectedComponent = templates.find(function (Component, idx) {
    if (idx === Number(templateId)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });`
```

And I display the components like this

```
<div>
  <SelectedComponents />
</div>
```

But I get an error as follows

```
index.js:1 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

What do I need to change to get this working as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `SelectedComponent` will be an object with `title` and `component` properties. You need to render just the component, and maybe pass in the `title` property if you wish.

```
//array of objects
const templates = [{
    title: "TemplateOne",
    component: TemplateOne,
}, {
    title: "TemplateTwo",
    component: TemplateTwo,
}]

//find the component and match the id passed in URL parameters
const {component: SelectedComponent, title} = templates.find(function(Component, idx) {
    if (idx === Number(templateId)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}) ?? {};

return (<div>
  {SelectedComponent && <SelectedComponent title={title} />} {/* Or don't include the title prop if you don't need to */}
</div>);
```

Comment: One hiccup will be if an invalid templateId gets entered in url

Comment: Yes, it needs to process validation when templateId doesn't match idx

Comment: @charlietfl fixed with `&&`

Comment: Thanks, its working now there is no error and and components are displayed as expected, I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

In react, the component's name should start with UpperLetter, and Array.prototype.find() function returns one element of Array.
i.e {title: 'blabla...', component: Blablaba}
So we need the component child as named as "Component" or UpperLetter leading Variable.
In here we can use it as following.

```
//array of objects
const templates = [
    {
      title: 'TemplateOne',
      component: TemplateOne,
    },
    {
      title: 'TemplateTwo',
      component: TemplateTwo,
    },
  ];
  const templateId = 4;
  //find the component and match the id passed in URL parameters
  const { component: Component } =
    templates.find((Component, idx) => {
      return idx === +templateId;
    }) || {};
  return <div>{Component && <Component />}</div>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution , also it works  upvoted because its usefully one

Comment: You should add `?? {}` at the end of the line below the `return false;` line, since `Array.prototype.find` returns `undefined` if there is no element found, and attempting to destructure from `undefined` throws an error. Destructing properties that aren't in an object doesn't throw an error, so using the null coalescence operator (`??`) can fix that